# Simpliest ag-grid filter example fails when adding 'ag-grid-enterprise'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

We have an ultra simple example with a sort option on a single column.

```
function Table(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={[
          { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
          { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
          { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
        ]}
      >
        <AgGridColumn filter field="make"></AgGridColumn>
        <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
        <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  )
```

The example works outside of our project, even when adding the 'ag-grid-enterprise' features.

However, when put into our project, the exact same code only works when not importing the enterprise package. Once we importing it (and expecting to get the enterprise grade filter) we get the following error:

```
ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGui' of undefined
    at EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407)
    at EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364)
    at HeaderComp.showMenu (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886)
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.BeanStub.addManagedListener (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793)
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.init (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethods (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002)
    at Context.wireBeans (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881)
    at Context.createBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869)
    at PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279)
    at VirtualList.componentCreator (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267)
    at VirtualList.insertRow (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196)
    at VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175)
    at VirtualList.drawVirtualRows (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
BeanStub.addManagedListener @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793
ToolPanelColumnComp.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267
VirtualList.insertRow @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196
VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175
VirtualList.drawVirtualRows @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
setTimeout (async)
VirtualList.refresh @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41140
PrimaryColsListPanel.flattenAndFilterModel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1374
PrimaryColsListPanel.setColumnLayout @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1305
ToolPanelColDefService.syncLayoutWithGrid @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4920
PrimaryColsListPanel.buildTreeFromWhatGridIsDisplaying @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1295
PrimaryColsListPanel.onColumnsChanged @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1286
PrimaryColsListPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1269
PrimaryColsPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4149
EnterpriseMenu.createColumnsPanel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36681
EnterpriseMenu.createTab @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36510
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
EnterpriseMenu.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
BeanStub.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2818
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36387
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.BeanStub.addManagedListener (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793)
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.init (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethods (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002)
    at Context.wireBeans (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881)
    at Context.createBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869)
    at PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279)
    at VirtualList.componentCreator (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267)
    at VirtualList.insertRow (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196)
    at VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175)
    at VirtualList.drawVirtualRows (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
BeanStub.addManagedListener @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793
ToolPanelColumnComp.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267
VirtualList.insertRow @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196
VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175
VirtualList.drawVirtualRows @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
setTimeout (async)
VirtualList.refresh @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41140
PrimaryColsListPanel.flattenAndFilterModel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1374
PrimaryColsListPanel.onColumnsChanged @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1292
PrimaryColsListPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1269
PrimaryColsPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4149
EnterpriseMenu.createColumnsPanel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36681
EnterpriseMenu.createTab @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36510
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
EnterpriseMenu.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
BeanStub.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2818
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36387
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
8[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took <N>ms
ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGui' of undefined
    at EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407)
    at EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364)
    at HeaderComp.showMenu (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886)
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36407
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.BeanStub.addManagedListener (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793)
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.init (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethods (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002)
    at Context.wireBeans (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881)
    at Context.createBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869)
    at PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279)
    at VirtualList.componentCreator (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267)
    at VirtualList.insertRow (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196)
    at VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175)
    at VirtualList.drawVirtualRows (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
BeanStub.addManagedListener @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793
ToolPanelColumnComp.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267
VirtualList.insertRow @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196
VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175
VirtualList.drawVirtualRows @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
setTimeout (async)
VirtualList.refresh @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41140
PrimaryColsListPanel.flattenAndFilterModel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1374
PrimaryColsListPanel.setColumnLayout @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1305
ToolPanelColDefService.syncLayoutWithGrid @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4920
PrimaryColsListPanel.buildTreeFromWhatGridIsDisplaying @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1295
PrimaryColsListPanel.onColumnsChanged @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1286
PrimaryColsListPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1269
PrimaryColsPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4149
EnterpriseMenu.createColumnsPanel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36681
EnterpriseMenu.createTab @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36510
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
EnterpriseMenu.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
BeanStub.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2818
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36387
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.BeanStub.addManagedListener (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793)
    at ToolPanelColumnComp.init (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.callLifeCycleMethods (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002)
    at Context.wireBeans (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881)
    at Context.createBean (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869)
    at PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279)
    at VirtualList.componentCreator (ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267)
    at VirtualList.insertRow (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196)
    at VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175)
    at VirtualList.drawVirtualRows (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158)
    at ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
BeanStub.addManagedListener @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2793
ToolPanelColumnComp.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1055
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
PrimaryColsListPanel.createComponentFromItem @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1279
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1267
VirtualList.insertRow @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41196
VirtualList.ensureRowsRendered @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41175
VirtualList.drawVirtualRows @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41158
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41145
setTimeout (async)
VirtualList.refresh @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:41140
PrimaryColsListPanel.flattenAndFilterModel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1374
PrimaryColsListPanel.onColumnsChanged @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1292
PrimaryColsListPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:1269
PrimaryColsPanel.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:4149
EnterpriseMenu.createColumnsPanel @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36681
EnterpriseMenu.createTab @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36510
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
EnterpriseMenu.init @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36464
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
Context.callLifeCycleMethodsOnBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1019
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.callLifeCycleMethods @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1002
Context.wireBeans @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:881
Context.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:869
BeanStub.createBean @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:2818
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36387
EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ ag-grid-enterprise.cjs.js:36364
HeaderComp.showMenu @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11893
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-community.cjs.js:11886
webpackHotDevClient.js:76 The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

My dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.2.2",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/pluralize": "^0.0.29",
    "ag-grid-community": "^24.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.1.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^24.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.6.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bizcharts": "^4.0.14",
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.7",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash-decorators": "^6.0.1",
    "marked": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file.

Comment: same problem, any solution yet ?

Comment: I have a same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the bellow code under setGridData :

```
import { AllModules } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
setGridData({
              modules: AllModules,
columnDefs: []
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes